# What should I do if I was told that I could start at the beginning of the month but haven't signed anything?

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, background-check, hiring, new-hires

I had my second Interview on the 16th and it went really well!

I was told that I could start the next Monday or at the beginning of the month. They had me fill out an Application and a Background Check Consent form.

I was told that it should take about 3-4 days and wasn't expecting to hear back till the next week and was shooting for a start day of the 1st of June. They did call me on Monday the 22nd and asked me to verify my information to make sure they had the right person. I answered their questions and was told that they should have everything cleared up soon and I should hear back the next day (the 23rd).

It's now the 29th and I understand that It's also Memorial Day weekend but I tried to follow up on Wednesday and Thursday (24th and 25th) leaving 2 messages since I didn't have email IDs, I still haven't received any contact from HR or anyone from the company.

What should I do?

Comment: "I was told that I could start the coming Monday or at the beginning of the month" - what date does this exactly mean? Did you say yes?

Comment: I did say yes. and the date that the Monday was referring to was the 22nd or the 1st of June. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have your background check cleared out yet?

Comment: That Is what I am waiting to hear back about. I have a family lawyer and asked him to pull my records and see if there was anything there that could be problematic just to be sure and it all came back Squeaky Clean.

Comment: In the worst case you could show up on the first of the month and check in person about the paperwork. It could be something simple like a misconfigured mailbox (or no one checking it, etc). Get HR's e-mail address so you'll have a second mode of contact.

Comment: Always go for the contract. No signy, no worky.

Comment: When you include location specific info like "Memorial Day", you should also mention the location. In this case, it doesn't matter because all that is relevant is that it was a location specific holiday. Nonetheless you should not assume that everyone celebrates or even knows about this Memorial Day. I was about to write an answer, but now I won't.

Comment: @sh5164 I Totally Agree!! This is another 'flag' and was a bit nervous that they haven't even talked about paperwork of that sort. Also not sure how to bring that up in conversation! Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Pretty Obvious and non aggressive. I like it! I shall try that! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

If it's not too much of an inconvenience, I'd show up on your agreed-upon time/date. They'll either send you home, or it'll light a fire under someone to move paperwork along.

Based on your experience with this place and your financial circumstances, this place may not be very well organized. In which case, don't burn any bridges and keep your job hunt hot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're in the US.  Usually, a start date is put into an offer letter (for perm jobs).  You haven't indicated that you've received one, so until you do, you don't have much to work with.  You could contact the company's HR department and ask for one.

I wouldn't advise that you just show up.  You may make a fool of yourself by doing so.  But in the meantime, don't stop your job search just yet.

Comment: If the OP was told that s/he could start at the beginning of the month, showing up at the beginning of the month would certainly not look foolish.

Comment: Not if whomever told her was intending to make a general statement instead of a specific one.

Comment: How could a general statement *not* mean that the OP can show up at the beginning of a month? I can't think of a meaning where this would be the case.